# ipc delays on for different primitives on a threaded applications

Tags: windows, multithreading, operating-system, ipc

I am writing a multi threaded application for Windows. It has a background thread/threads which generate objects which are fed into UI thread. 
When there is no work I want UI thread to sleep. To achieve the synchronization between threads, I can think of multiple options. However, I am wondering what are quarks of each primitive in terms of context switches.

The background thread may want to run continuously and would like to wake the UI thread at precisely correct moment.

1. Condition Variable/Semaphore: I can use shared memory to pass the data and cond.var or semaphore to synchronize. In that case when does the context switch happens? Does it happen the moment I signal or it is after the quanta is over for a thread. Is one better than other?
2. sockets: I can run a server and client in each thread and can create a stream instead of shared memory. I think here context switch will happen the moment time quanta is over.
3. Is there any other options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use the method1 because it uses shared memory, single process memory to communicate with the other threads with in the same process. Advantages will be that there is no ipc overhead (like the send/recv or write/read) invloved as such in case of 2.

In either of the two cases the thread waiting on the conditional variable, lock or waiting on the socket for reading data, will enter into the wait state, means that it will get scheduled off from the run queue. As soon the thread calls the pthread_cond_wait or pthread_mutex_lock, there is a system call that gets triggered (in case of linux) and makes the calling thread enter into sleep. in case of sockets the thread calling the recv will be put into the sleep.